# getting error while creating phonegap app through iOS api command

Tags: ios, linux, cordova

I am newbie in phonegap and I tried to install it on my mac machine but I am getting an error. I am following [this link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html) as reference.

Here is my code which I am running on my mac machine.

```
./create ~/desktop/hello com.test.hello hello and i am getting error as:

./create: line 66: dirname: command not found
/Users/administrator/Desktop/phonegap-2.9.0/lib/ios/bin/replaces: line 28: sed: command not found
/Users/administrator/Desktop/phonegap-2.9.0/lib/ios/bin/replaces: line 28: sed: command not found
/Users/administrator/Desktop/phonegap-2.9.0/lib/ios/bin/replaces: line 28: sed: command not found
/Users/administrator/Desktop/phonegap-2.9.0/lib/ios/bin/replaces: line 28: sed: command not found
/Users/administrator/Desktop/phonegap-2.9.0/lib/ios/bin/replaces: line 28: sed: command not found
/Users/administrator/Desktop/phonegap-2.9.0/lib/ios/bin/replaces: line 28: sed: command not found
/Users/administrator/Desktop/phonegap-2.9.0/lib/ios/bin/replaces: line 28: sed: command not found
/Users/administrator/Desktop/phonegap-2.9.0/lib/ios/bin/replaces: line 28: sed: command not found
/Users/administrator/Desktop/phonegap-2.9.0/lib/ios/bin/replaces: line 28: sed: command not found
./create: /Users/administrator/Desktop/phonegap-2.9.0/lib/ios/bin/update_cordova_subproject: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Although the hello.xcodeproj is created at given path but when i try to open it in Xcode getting this error:

```
Project /Users/administrator/Desktop/hello/hello.xcodeproj cannot be opened because the project file cannot be parsed.
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Don't ask us to follow a guide. Instead, post the exact command which is giving your problems.

Comment: ./create ~/desktop/hello com.test.hello hello     command is giving error.

Comment: phonegap is installed on your mac?

Comment: I don't know how `./create` looks like, but `line 28: sed: command not found` indicates you do not have `sed` installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that phonegap is not installed correctly.
The easiest way is to download node-js from nodejs.org first and then use its package manager to install phonegap.

```
sudo npm install -g phonegap
```

After installing phonegap you could use

```
phonegap local create com.test.hello hello
```

To initialize your project

Comment: When I am running the above command getting error: -bash: sudo: command not found. And my xcode is also not working now.

Comment: How does your $PATH look like. Type `echo $PATH` in your Terminal. Maybe your path variables are wrong. `sudo` normally is in `/usr/bin/` . Is this missing ?

Comment: My path is like this: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin

Comment: Your PATH looks correct. Please type `/usr/bin/sudo` instead of just `sudo`. What does your terminal say ?

Comment: It's say -bash: /usr/bin/sudo: No such file or directory

Comment: And what does `ls -la /usr/bin` say ? It should return a list of the content in the `bin` directory. Do you see `sudo` in there ? Try `which sudo` also please.

Comment: Only an idea: Maybe there's something broken in the permission rights. Start the Disk Utility Tool on MacOSX, select your harddrive on the left side e.g. `Macintosh HD` and then click on `Repair Disc Permission`

Comment: I have revert back all installation and again install node.js then downloaded the phone gap archive and follow the phone gap iOS api instructions..

Comment: Accepting means clicking the ✓ to the left of the answer. ;)